# Older PIX 515e running 8.0(4)28: Can't get internet access to work with DHCP on outside interface

Tags: cisco-pix

Ok.. I admit it. I am probably missing something simple. A little help?

I have an older PIX 515e that I am trying to get running. The outside interface is connected to a cable modem and configured for DHCP. This interface gets assigned an IP from the ISP so this part seems to be working. My understanding is that using the command  should automatically set the static route for the ISP gateway. If I  this seems to be the case. From the console, I can also ping the ISP gateway and any other site (yahoo.com) that I try.

The inside interface is setup with a static address of 10.0.1.10 and this returns a ping from the inside clients. DHCP on the internal network is handled by a 2012R2 machine and this service as well as DNS is also working (except for DNS forwarding while the PIX is being tested)

However, clients cannot access the internet. No ping replies, etc. I believe this is either a routing issue or a NAT/PAT issue. I am behind the 8-ball on this area of Cisco configuration and could use some help. Posted below is my current running config. I have tried a few of the config guides found on the net, but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Thanks!
Michael

```
: Saved
:

PIX Version 8.0(4)28 
!
hostname GripPix

domain-name Grip.com

enable password ... encrypted

passwd ... encrypted

names

!

interface Ethernet0

 nameif outside

 security-level 0

 ip address dhcp setroute 

!

interface Ethernet1

 nameif inside

 security-level 100

 ip address 10.0.1.10 255.255.0.0 

!

interface Ethernet2

 shutdown

 no nameif

 no security-level

 no ip address

!

interface Ethernet3

 shutdown

 no nameif

 no security-level

 no ip address

!

interface Ethernet4

 shutdown

 no nameif

 no security-level

 no ip address

!

interface Ethernet5

 shutdown

 no nameif

 no security-level

 no ip address

!

ftp mode passive

dns server-group DefaultDNS

 domain-name Grip.com

same-security-traffic permit inter-interface

same-security-traffic permit intra-interface

access-list outside_in extended permit icmp any any echo-reply 

access-list outside_in extended deny ip any any log 

pager lines 24

logging enable

logging asdm informational

mtu outside 1500

mtu inside 1500

no failover

icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1

asdm image flash:/asdm-613.bin

no asdm history enable

arp timeout 14400

global (outside) 1 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0

global (outside) 1 interface

nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0

timeout xlate 3:00:00

timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02

timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00

timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00

timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute

timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00

dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy

aaa authentication serial console LOCAL 

aaa authentication telnet console LOCAL 

aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 

http server enable

http 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 inside

no snmp-server location

no snmp-server contact

snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart

crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800

crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000

telnet 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 inside

telnet timeout 5

ssh timeout 5

console timeout 0

threat-detection basic-threat

threat-detection statistics access-list

no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept

!

class-map inspection-default

 match default-inspection-traffic

class-map inspection_default

 match default-inspection-traffic

!

!

policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map

 parameters

  message-length maximum 512

policy-map global_policy

 class inspection_default

  inspect dns preset_dns_map 

  inspect ftp 

  inspect h323 h225 

  inspect h323 ras 

  inspect rsh 

  inspect rtsp 

  inspect esmtp 

  inspect sqlnet 

  inspect skinny  

  inspect sunrpc 

  inspect xdmcp 

  inspect sip  

  inspect netbios 

  inspect tftp 

  inspect http 

  inspect icmp 

!

service-policy global_policy global

prompt hostname context 

Cryptochecksum:9cceeff3166fd745e3569853ea5c178c

: end

asdm image flash:/asdm-613.bin

no asdm history enable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I did something dumb. The clients were actually able to access the internet, but I didn't know because I wasn't actually trying to browse, etc. I simply opened a cmd window and ran "ping www.yahoo.com -t"

My assumption was that once I got a ping reply, the gateway was working. What I neglected to do was allow ICMP traffic through the NAT firewall. So even though my clients could actually browse, etc, I didn't get the ping replies so I assumed I wasn't getting through. Once I enabled ICMP traffic it was fine. I felt a little sheepish on that one but live and learn I guess.